# Wolfram Alpha Step By Step For Systems of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wolfram-alpha

Does anyone know if wolfram alpha has step by step solutions for systems of differential equations? When I input them, it comes up with an answer but it does not give me the step by step solution. I would like it just for practicing purposes.

For example, I input the following into wolfram but it does not show me the step by step option as opposed to just inputting 1 linear ODE.

```
solve[{x' = -6x + 2y, y' = -20x + 6y}]
```

Thanks

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't think that assumption is a good one. I want to use it for practice, my homework doesn't involve much hand solving but I want additional practice for exams

Comment: @ThomasAndrews nonetheless thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases} x'=-6x+2y \\ y'=-20x+6y \end{cases}$$
One can solve it with matrix calculus or with the method of substitution (below) :

$2y=x'+6x \quad \to \quad 2y'=x''+6x'$

$$2y'=-40x+12y=-40x+6(x'+6x)=x''+6x'$$
$$x''+4x=0$$
$$x(t)=C_1\cos(2t)+C_2\sin(2t)$$
Then, you can compute $y(t)=\frac{1}{2}x'(t)+3x(t)$